# sql query to return single record per group id in sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to fetch record agency wise group by but I want this in a pattern that I have mentioned below.

All record should be fetched but in terms of grouping - a set of all unique agency records first and then in continuous process.

Here is my table:

[image]

Desired Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by agency_id order by person),
         agency_id;
```

The second key is so the rows are in the same order in each group.

Comment: any other query or alternate for this? As I am not able to use it along with Laravel Eloquent query with where conditions. Because Order By comes before where conditions and gives error. Using DB Raw query with this. Any help?

Comment: please help on this